# What are the best practices for hardening a php.ini file?

Tags: appsec, web-application, php, hardening

In order to secure a PHP installation, what are the best settings for a php.ini file? What is absolutely vital in terms of security? What is recommended for most use cases?

Comment: You can use the following script to check your PHP security settings <a href="http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/02/hardening-and-securing-php-on-linux/">http://www.idontplaydarts.com/2011/02/hardening-and-securing-php-on-linux/</a>

Comment: @user3201 Sadly, gives a 404 nowadays.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I find a good step for hardening your php.ini file is to use the [PHPSecInfo](http://phpsec.org/projects/phpsecinfo/index.html) tool, this tool will outline what settings you have currently in your php.ini that may cause a security risk. 
In addition to using that tool give this article on [Hardening PHP from php.ini](http://www.madirish.net/?article=229) a look its good and picks up most of the major concerns.

Personally the two main things I always make sure are configured correctly are:

- **display_errors** - On a production server this should be turned Off and the errors should be logged to a file.
- **group_id** - This is set to an appropriate value for a low privileged user e.g. www-data not root.

Comment: **allow_url_include** - if you don't include PHP files from remote hosts (which seems like a silly thing to begin with), turn this setting OFF. Only harm can come from it.

Comment: There are additional requirements necessary to prevent PHP information disclosures in addition to the display_errors php.ini file directive. There are other places that one needs to check, and these should be verified if at all possible. I suggest looking into the inspathx tool.

Comment: phpsecinfo hasn't been updated since April 2007. It looks quite stale, especially compared to the number of developments in PHP over the last 4.5 years.

Answer (score 2):

Another php.ini hardening could be resources limiting, as described in configuration file itself "Resource Limits". Generally, it depends on your web-application which limits should be set up. As I know, for example, for Wordpress installation 32M memory `memory_limit` is not enough. Other applications requires longer time to run `max_execution_time`. Also, you would like to cut down maximum time that is allowed for data to be transferred `max_input_time`. Maximum POST size can also be limited `post_max_size`. All of above mentioned configurations generally will help to avoid DoS conditions.

About `maqic_quotes_gpc`, it is quite annoying, and as of PHP5.4 it was removed. Developers often automatically removes slashes by detecting this setting.