# How to create your own RBL DNS Blacklist to prevent spam

Tags: network, dns, spam

I am getting sick of reporting the same old chinese emails to Spamcop now and would like to make my own small RBL list that I can easily add blocks of IP's to.
I have a spare PC and static IP address ready, just looking for some pointers on the best thing to install on it in order to make an RBL server.

TIA

Comment: Added "Spam" to the title for SEO :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with a standard dns server, but I have seen [rbldnsd](http://www.corpit.ru/mjt/rbldnsd.html) which appears to be made for this purpose - the main feature being that it allows you to blacklist sites very easily by adding them to a mysql database.

Found a quick [instruction page here](http://www.blue-quartz.com/rbl/).

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd already found that site and was hoping for something a bit more user friendly as I'm unfamiliar with Linux and wouldn't know where to start for example when it says "Step 6: Edit the /etc/sysconfig/rbldnsd config file". If it's the only solution, I'll have to give it a go

Comment: Ahhh - I would definitely advise a bit of linux practice. I wouldn't know how to do it on a different platform, but Linux can be a bit baffling until you are used to it. The good thing is that there is an awful lot of documentation and howto guidance on the web, so setting up a linux server with minimal services shouldn't be too complicated. And in terms of editing, you can always use a linux with a GUI (not normally the ideal for a server, but could make your life easier) and then you can just click on the notepad equivalent (eg gedit)

Comment: In fact in reading that howto, almost every command is listed there. The only one missing is that edit one, and that may be because people use different editors. For example I would use vi at the command line, but if you want to use that get yourself a list of vi commands: http://www.eng.hawaii.edu/Tutor/vi.html

Comment: OK I'm going to have a go - you're right about the instructions, it seems pretty straightforward when looked at in more detail. I've always wanted to find out what I can do with Linux and this seems a good oppurtunity to build a test server. (I've just downloaded Ubuntu 10.10 Server Edition and would appreciate any comments before I go ahead with it)

Comment: Well, you could have a quick look at http://security.stackexchange.com/q/993/485 - some thoughts on hardening linux, nealmcb's answer is Ubuntu specific.