# What are the best IT auditing guidelines for Red Hat Linux 5.x+, including the critical data protection?

Tags: linux, audit

Currently, I am a junior application consultant and we are maintaining huge amounts of redhat machines as servers. I am given the chance and liberty by my boss (unbelieveable!) to go do my own research regarding the security of our own systems. So I thought, maybe I should ask around here.... Hope you don't mind :)

So the question is: What should be audited in a Red Hat 5.x+ system to ensure the safety and make sure that proper measures will be taken to realize the given points here below:

- Critical data protection
- illegal access prevention
- system integrity
- uptime
- system updates and patches are most recent
- and etc...

What I want to achieve with this is to create a uniform and secure process to audit our systems and chart the status to intervene. In the end, I would like to look for possibilities to integrate this process with our monitoring systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

look at this CIS benchmark  [RHEL 5 Benchmark](http://benchmarks.cisecurity.org/tools2/linux/CIS_RHEL5_Benchmark_v1.1.pdf)

Comment: This one is pretty much like what I was looking for :) But of course, this one is very much specific on RHEL systems which I asked for, too. Thank you very much :) I wish I could Vote up, becuase this answer and the one below is all I needed for a start :) More questions will follow later.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't 100% duplicated, but have a read of our [Hardening a Linux Server](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/993/485) question - what this will help you do is cover off security controls across your installed Linux server base.

If you are including Linux desktops in your remit, some of the recommendations on that question will be less appropriate, but at least in thinking about what access users need, you will get a better view of controls required.

But step one for any hardening is to understand what and where your assets are - don't spend money protecting something that doesn't need to be protected.