# Things to do to ensure that data is secured on my virtual server

Tags: ssh, mysql, tcp

I'm not much of a server administrator but I'm maintaining a virtual server with Ubuntu OS where my website is hosted. I often use ssh, ftp and MySQL. As my website gets popular, I want to make sure the data and source code are secure. What are the things I should do?

For example, recently I decided to switch to login using SSH keys only for every user except for the root account. Probably, I should also do something similar for my database. I'm looking for good, easy things to implement.

Comment: http://hardenubuntu.com/ try this one. As i dont use the ubuntu/linux crap i cant tell how up to date it is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hardening Linux Server](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/993/hardening-linux-server)

Comment: Do you need to make MySQL available remotely? That's a bit attack vector. If you can only access MySQL locally it will be more secure.

Comment: @NeilSmithline, yes I do connect to MySQL remotely through dbForge. I think I can restrict the range of IP addresses to allow remote connections from. Any other ideas?

Comment: Your architecture doesn't use the standard [three tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture#Three-tier_architecture). That architecture puts DB security in the logic layer so you have to work around that. Two-tier arch can make sense for smaller apps (presumably like yours). Restricting IPs seems a good idea. Changing to non-default port may help. Firewall rules. Strong DB passwords. Restricting DB admins to localhost only. Whatever you can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by reading about some (Ubuntu specific) best practices. Like:

1. Closing unnecessary ports.
2. Removing unnecessary packages.
3. Setting up some basic [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo) rules.
4. Setting up a Web Application Firewall like [mod_security](https://www.modsecurity.org).
5. Look into DNS solutions like [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com) to prevent heavy load on your VPS processes in case of DDoS-attacks.
6. Working with SSH keys and/or setting up a two factor authentication method like [Authy-SSH](https://github.com/authy/authy-ssh).
7. Setting up downtime-monitoring like [Pingdom](https://www.pingdom.com) or [UptimeRobot](http://uptimerobot.com).
8. Do some software specific security hardening for example for Apache, PHP and MySQL.
9. Get regularly tested by the use of Vulnerability scanners and/or penetration testers.

It's important to regularly update all software packages and the Ubuntu kernel and you can take a look into full disk encryption with LVM/LUKS.

*Also I recommend to take a look at http://hardenubuntu.com/ like user PolymathMonkey suggested.*