# Is a newly installed server with no services running (but connected to the web) at risk?

Tags: linux, server, patching, exposure

A new server has just been installed but literally has nothing else running on it, no services setup to SSH in or anything yet (it's a Linux server).

However, it is hooked up to the web so I can start pulling software down and installing it.

So here is the question, is it at risk whilst it is plugged in? Obviously no AV atm as mentioned above and also I'm not all that savvy on routers and the protection they can offer...

Hmm, maybe one thing to note is that it's the latest software so the server OS is up to date.

Comment: Be aware that a default build almost certainly has services running...read http://security.stackexchange.com/q/993/485

Comment: How is it hooked up to the Internet? If it's connected to a consumer-grade home router just like a regular desktop computer, it is probably protected by the router's NAT firewall, which blocks all incoming connections by default (making it highly unlikely that the server could be compromised from outside). It will not be accessible from outside at all unless you forward ports to it or put it in a DMZ, by modifying your router settings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use **nmap** to get a better view of the (network)services it is running:

```
nmap -sS -v <your_server> -sV -p1-65535
```

and **lsof** to view the current inbound/outbound connections to the box.

```
lsof -i
```

If there are no processes listening on any port then the server is reasonably safe. If new services are installed(i.e. ssh server) it is recommended that strong(>8 characters, alpha numeric, upper case, lower case, special characters) passwords are used(with SSH some argue it's better to use public key authentication). 
For added safety you could also install **fail2ban** and run an updating script regularly(i.e. as a cron job).

For example, an update script(on Debian/Ubuntu) may look like:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo sh -c "apt-get update;apt-get dist-upgrade;apt-get autoremove;apt-get autoclean"
```

Installing fail2ban on Ubuntu/Debian can be done using:

```
sudo apt-get install fail2ban
```

In order to configure fail2ban it is recommended to make a copy of the default configuration file:

```
sudo cp /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

and work on the copy:

```
sudo vim /etc/fail2ban/jail.local
```

The most relevant entries are **ignoreip**, **bantime**, **findtime** and **maxretry**.

Increasing the **bantime** and **maxretry** values statistically improve security.