# How to secure a dedicated linux server running a LAMP stack for commercial E-commerce use

Tags: linux, webserver, hardening

To be more specific, I would like to get some help, either through a tutorial or through a book, on how to configure an apache server to run securely and minimize the risks for commercial use.

-Important to note, I am not asking how to install it or minimally configure it, as I have learned to do this. I would like to further this knowledge by getting help on where to look or how to configure it the way E-commerce websites would to keep it secure.

I do understand this may be vague, and so I will not be expecting an in-depth tutorial, but if I could get help or tips on where I should look. I have tried everywhere, but it all ends with just installing it, and minimally securing it for testing purposes.

Comment: I think that this question fits more to [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Is there a reason you wish to install and maintain a server over getting dedicated hosting?  Many advantages come with paying for dedicated hosting.  Typically you get redundancy service which equates to less down time, which is a big thing for e-commerce.  Also, this approach allows you to let a group of experts handle security issues which really would take a lot more than a few tutorials to get the hang of.  Server security really is a full time job...  There are many many more benefits to going for paid hosting...

Comment: @Kenneth Setting up and maintaining your own server has one very important advice: You can physically kick it, once in a while...

Comment: @YannisRizos ... So very very true!!! :)

Answer (score 9):

This is really a pretty stinking huge question. Based on your chosen tags it *looks* like you're asking for guidance on a LAMP stack, so we'll focus on that. There are already a number of related [hardening](/questions/tagged/hardening) questions posted, so for some additional insights check out these questions:
[MySQL Server Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/1138/mysql-server-hardening)
[Hardening Linux Server](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/993/hardening-linux-server)
[What are the best practices for hardening a php.ini file?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/563/what-are-the-best-practices-for-hardening-a-php-ini-file)
[Apache Server Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77/apache-server-hardening)

The specific techniques you take could depend highly on your environment and how your server will be used. Warning, this can take a lot of work in a test environment to build out and get done right. Followed by a lot of work to integrate into your production environment, and more importantly, business process.

First, however, check to see if your organization has any hardening policies, as those might be the most directly relevant. If not, depending on your role, this might be a great time to build them out. I would also recommend tackling each component separately from the bottom up.

**The L**
There are lots of good guides available to help you out. This list may or may not help you depending on your distribution.

- [Center for Internet Security Benchmarks](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform) - Distribution specific for the major flavors
- [CentOS Hardening HowTo](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/OS_Protection) - Follows closely to the CIS RHEL5 guide, but is a much easier read
- [NIST SP800-123 - Guide to General Server Security](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/guidance/security_configuration_guides/current_guides.shtml)
- [NSA Hardening Factsheets](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-123/SP800-123.pdf) - Not as recently updated as CIS, but still mostly applicable
- [Tiger](http://www.nongnu.org/tiger/) - Live System Security Auditing Software

**The A**
Apache can be fun to secure.  I find it easier to harden the OS and maintain usability than either Apache or PHP.

- [Apache Server Hardening](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77/apache-server-hardening) - This question on the IT Security sister site has lots of good information.
- [Center for Internet Security Benchmarks](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform) - Again, Apache benchmarks.
- [Apache Security Tips](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/security_tips.html) - Straight from the Apache project, it looks like it covers the basics
- [DISA Hardening Checklist](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/downloads/zip/unclassified_web_srr_checklist_apache_v6r1-12_20100423.zip) - Checklist from the DoD Information Assurance guys

**The M**

- [Center for Internet Security Benchmarks](http://cisecurity.org/en-us/?route=downloads.multiform) - Again, but for MySQL benchmarks
- [OWASP MySQL Hardening](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Backend_Security_Project_MySQL_Hardening)
- [General Security Guidelines](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/security-guidelines.html) - Basic checklist from the project devs

**The P**
This runs headlong into the whole idea of Secure Programming Practices, which is an entire discipline of its own. SANS and OWASP have a ridiculous amount of information on the subject, so I won't try to replicate it here. I will focus on the runtime configuration and let your developers worry about the rest. Sometimes the 'P' in LAMP refers to Perl, but usually PHP. I am assuming the latter.

- [Hardening PHP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/563/what-are-the-best-practices-for-hardening-a-php-ini-file) - Some minor discussion, also on IT Security SE site.
- [Hardened PHP Project](http://www.hardened-php.net/) - Main project that produces [Suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/index.html), an attempt to patch the PHP application to project against certain types of attacks.
- [Hardening PHP With Suhosin](http://www.phpfreaks.com/tutorial/hardening-php-with-suhosin) - A brief HowTo specifically for Suhosin
- [Hardening PHP from php.ini](http://www.madirish.net/?article=229) - Short, but not bad discussion on some of the security related runtime options

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at [Suhosin for PHP](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/) and [mod_sec](http://www.modsecurity.org/). Both are very good.

Comment: -1 `Both are very good.` is not an answer. You should consider expanding the answer to tell us what your suggestions are about, why you recommended them - what's so great about them. Adding to that, Suhosin has had no activity since 2007 (essentially a dead project)... Also, why did you choose to format the links as code?